# Unable to deployApp due to no 'kable' package

Tags: r, shiny, kable

I have been trying to run my first shinyapp from Rstudio.

The app loads but is undeployed. It stops running with the error:

> Preparing to deploy application...DONE
> Uploading bundle for application: 8122435...Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
> Package 'kable' not available in repository or locally
> Error: Unable to retrieve package records for the following packages: - 'kable'

then when trying to install package "kable"

> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘kable’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Is this a temporary problem? Is there an easy way to go to an older version of R on a mac? I have tried loading kable package from other repositories aswell.

Any advice?

Comment: kable comes from knitr package.

Comment: When deploying apps (to shiny-server, Connect, or shinyapps.io), the deploying functions look at the app to try to infer which packages are needed on the remote end; while it's good, it is imperfect and does not necessarily catch `::`-references to functions. If you add `library(knitr)` (in this case) to the top of one of your script files (e.g., `app.R`, `global.R`, or `server.R`, but only you know since we don't have your app files) and try again to deploy

Comment: Do you have `library(kable)` in your source code? Because it seems to be trying to load a package that doesn't exist for some reason and there is no package named `kable`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.